# In App Purchases For IOS 7 Simulator Possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

Seems like apple once again took the rights from ios 7 simulator to test inapp purchases. I have my game with other version of ios simulator running well to test in app purchases but suddenly it stopped on ios 7 simulator throwing me the error "can not connect to itunes store."

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to give more information than that. And you might want to ask in the Apple developer forums since iOS 7 is still covered by the NDA

Comment: Yeah Right. Let me contact developers then. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an SDK which is under NDA

Comment: @ColinE No, this is not off topic due to the NDA. SO doesn't care (though developers should).

Comment: @maddy - the comment above was added as part of the standard close-question process. StackOverflow doesn't have an option for 'close because this is a question about an NDA topic'!

Comment: First Sorry if it is unrelated. It seems like many other guys are also facing this issue even on their real devices may be. Here is some discussion about that. "https://devforums.apple.com/message/864948#864948"

Comment: I am also having this problem. I am using MKStoreKit and it works on iOS 6 simulator and device, but not on iOS 7 simulator (Xcode 5 / GM). I have not tested on a device running iOS 7 GM however.

Comment: As per apple doc, they are not supporting in-app purchase in iOS7 simulator. You need to use device to test in-app purchase.

Comment: @Nandha, Yeah thanks, seems like they are not supporting on ios 7 simulator. Could you send me the doc link i can verify with they are not doing this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051 in that refer iOS simulator.

Comment: Yeah right you are. I see under IOS Simulator heading. They are not supporting in app purchases in simulator. Thanks Nandha :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not think that you can do that in the iPhone iOS7 Simulator. The Simulator does not have access to the app store or iTunes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but anyway it was possible to test in app purchases in the simulator for iOS 6 for instance.

Comment: Maybe we could be looking at a future X-Code update...

Comment: Attaching link to Xcode 5.0 release notes that confirm that StoreKit (and In-App purchases) do not work in the iOS simulator. Look under Known Issues > iOS Simulator in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241