# in-app store purchasing via Simulator

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, simulator

I am unable to make in-app purchases via Simulator.
I know I was able to do this before (perhaps about a year ago).

But now, after a long hiatus from app development, i'm now unable to do so.

The error i get is `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`

Doing a brief search on the net seems to indicate that in-app purchases via Simulator is no longer supported.

Can anybody confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allow in-app purchases from the simulator. You'll need a real device. 
[In App Purchases For IOS 7 Simulator Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755824/in-app-purchases-for-ios-7-simulator-possible)